# ¿Como le cambio el color(aleatorio) a una figura en Java?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como puedo cambiar el color a un circulo, pero que sea aleatorio, cada vez que reinicio el programa

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Con un random:

int color = Math.random()*6 + 1   // Esto da valores entre 1.0 y 7.0 excluido el 7.0

Y en un array pones los colores y le dices que lo asigne por el numero aleatorio que te salga.